# margin collapsing

Tags: css

1. Do vertical margins between a floated box and any other box collapse?
2. Do margins of absolutely and relative boxes collapse?

Comment: Have you tried testing these out?

Comment: i tried but in both case boxes are displayed on top of each other, so how can i know margin collapsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Float margins don't collapse.  According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins):

   > Vertical margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not even between a float and its in-flow children).
2. Absolute positioned margins don't collapse.  According to the same [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins):

   > Margins of absolutely positioned boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children).

Answer (score 0):

No, margin collapses only between two `adjacent block` elements when they have margin towards each-other.